# How to pass a User Id using params as props In Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here we are:
I have a login View. The User will log in. After he login, I will get UserID and pass it to the next View(components) using props.

**Login.Vue**

```
.then(res => {if (res.status === 200){
                console.log(res.data['id'])
                this.$router.push({name:'Contact', params:{userID: res.data['id'] }}) }
            })
```

**Contacts.vue**

```
export default {
    name: "contact",
    props:["userID"],
    data() {
        return {
            UserID: this.$route.params.userID,
           
        };
    },
```

I will get The userID after the login as shown below:

[image]

However, When the page is reloaded or refreshed the UserID will be lost:

[image]

So How can I save it when the page is reloaded?

**Update: :**

router-> **index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Login from "../views/Login.vue";
import Register from "../views/Register.vue";
import Contact from "../views/Contact.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        props: true
    },
    {
        path: "/register",
        name: "Register",
        component: Register
    },

    {
        path: "/contact",
        name: "Contact",
        component: Contact,
        props: true
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

export default router;
```

**Contact.vue components:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: show how you defined the route `Contacts` and all its child routes

Comment: @Anatoly I have already updated the question. May you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `userId` as a param in your rooute to be able to pass user id from URL as props to your component:

```
{
        path: "/contact/:userId",
        name: "Contact",
        component: Contact,
        props: true
    }
```

See [Passing props to reactive components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you get user data once when you try to log in on the login page and didn't save it in the right place. simply you just can save your user data in local storage when getting the response from API.

**Login.Vue**

```
.then(res => {
 if (res.status === 200) {
  console.log(res.data['id'])
  this.$router.push({ name:'Contact' })
  
  localStorage.setItem('user_id', res.data['id']);
 }
})
```

and after that, if you check your Local Storage in Application tab in your browser developer tools, you can see `user_id` in Local Storage.
now you can get `user_id` from local storage in any component you want:

**Contacts.vue**

```
export default {
 name: 'Contact',

 data() {
  return {
   UserId: localStorage.getItem('user_id');
  };
 },
}
```